# How do I uninstall Drush 9 and install Drush 8?

Tags: drush

I take it I can't manage Drupal 7 sites with drush 9 so I'm trying to install Drush 8. But first I have to remove 9.
I tried `composer global remove drush/drush` but it gives errors:

> drush is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
>       Package "drush" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
>       Loading composer repositories with package information
>       Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>       Nothing to install or update
>       Generating autoload files

I know it is installed because drush -version lists 9.7.1

Comment: First, locate your drush executable. You may have installed using a package manager or installed globally. If you are using Linux (and OSX probably) type ```whereis drush``` in the shell/console/terminal. Once you know where Drush is located you may have more information on install method so you also know how to install it.

Comment: Thanks. In OS X Terminal I had to use which. Whereis didn't return anything. It says "/Users/paulmorris/.composer/vendor/bin/drush". I think that means it was installed globally with composer?

Comment: Yes, that it what is seems. Check ```/Users/paulmorris/.composer/composer.json``` to see if it's there. If not, you can probably remove ```/Users/paulmorris/.composer/drush``` and ```/Users/paulmorris/.composer/vendor/bin/drush```.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work. I might have accidentally download Drush 9 but used the drush 8 instructions to install. There were a few other places I had to delete including /usr/local/bin/drush, and ~/.drush